# Can't get Debugger for Chrome to work, configured debug type pwa-chrome is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to use VS Code to debug the development version of Visual Studio Code as in the contribution docs [located here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#debugging).

However, I keep getting the error that the `Configured debug type 'pwa-chrome' is not supported` after trying to follow the step `Choose the Launch VS Code launch configuration from the launch dropdown in the Debug viewlet and press F5`.

I've tried looking online for answers and have seen that `useV3` needs to be set to `false` ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/983) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89578)), but I've verified that my `useV3` is set to `false` as well as installed/uninstalled Debugger for Chrome while disabling other extensions, yet nothing seems to work.

I'd love to get some help with this so I can get to contributing to the code base within the next couple of days :)

Answer (score 3):

Check this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89578) !!!

Make sure you have following extensions installed !!:

- Javascript Debugger (Nightly)
- Debugger for Chrome

### Note!!

There is similar Javascript Debugger extensions.
Choose right one with (nightly)!

[image]

Comment: Installing js-debug-nightly solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update VSCode to the latest version 1.50.1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Installing JavaScript Debugger (Nightly) solved it for me.